# How can I cast shadow on background with nodes

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, shaders, masking, world

I shot a video in a chroma room (object in front of green background), after I have eliminated the green (masked away). Please, can someone explain how I will cast the shadow of the object on my new background? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this question is animation nodes related?

Comment: I am working on music video, not animation. I just created a hall with blender as a background.

Comment: Not sure about the way you did. If you use the video image sequence as texture on a plane, then it is possible to cast shadow, which works for Cycles and BI. Anyway, more info needed to undersand your question better.

Comment: If I use it as a texture, do u sure I will have a good output?

Comment: [Here](http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=107118) is a simple material setup for Cycles. FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your subject cut out, you can use its alpha channel to make a shadow layer with the compositor:

[image]

- After the color keying is taken care of, use the Separate RGBA node to get the alpha channel.
- Run it through a translate node so you can move the shadow.
- The alpha channel will need to be inverted with an invert node.
- Multiply the shadow with the background and use the multiply factor to control the opacity of the shadow.
- Run the shadow-background and color key results through an alpha over node to put the color keyed result over the background-shadow.